# What does (object) do next to class name in python?

Tags: python, class, object

When you declare a class in python, I often see `(object)` written next to the class name.

```
class someClass(object):
    def __init__(self, some_variable):
        ...
    ...
```

Is this same as writing below?

```
class someClass: # didn't write (object) here.
    def __init__(self, some_variable):
        ...
    ...
```

I don't really see any difference in terms of how they function. Is it just a way to clarify that `someClass` is a `subclass` of `object`? and is it a good practice to explicitly write `object` when I make a `class`?

Comment: I like @jwodder's answer for the explanation.  As far as best practices go, I tend to explicitly use `(object)` just so my code can be used with both Python 2.x and 3 with minimal confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python 2, making `someClass` a subclass of `object` turns `someClass` into a "new-style class," whereas without `(object)` it's just a "classic class."  See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) or [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) for information on the differences between them; the short answer is that you should always use new-style classes for the benefits they bring.

In Python 3, all classes are "new-style," and writing `(object)` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.x, they are the same, when you declare:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

it inherits from `object` implicitly.

For more information visit [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)